# How to add a comment form in a DetailView in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a comment form in a DetailView in Django and I don't know how to approach it. I've been able to do it with a function based view but I don't know how to start using a class based view.

My **views.py for the DetailView**:

```
class BusinesDetaiView(DetailView):
queryset = Business.objects.all()
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you read the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Comment: If you don't really know what you are doing I would suggest to use either mptt-django or check a tutorial on the topic. Writing a comment section can be tricky. You could also use https://disqus.com. Its also written in Django/Python.

Answer (score 0):

Create a FormView template and put in the action of the form the url to the view

views:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView

class CommentForm(FormView):
    model = CommentModel
    form_class = CommentModelForm
```

html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url "commentform_create" %}">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```